# Nifi receive full text tweet

Tags: hadoop, twitter, bigdata, apache-nifi

I can get 140 characters tweet on apache nifi but I'm trying to get the full 280 character tweets off of twitter. 
It creates link after 140 characters.How can solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any configuration option in the current GetTwitter processor to get all text in a tweet. GetTwitter processor uses [Hosebird client](https://github.com/twitter/hbc) library in the back to interface with Twitter API which does not support fetching full tweets.

There is an issue in GitHub project page regarding this requirement - https://github.com/twitter/hbc/issues/152